# C# Movimentação de Arquivos

Tags: c#

Estou fazendo uma aplicação, e em determinado momento ela faz o seguinte:

Verifica se um arquivo que vai ser criado já existe em um diretório (saída), se já existe, ele manda para a pasta Erros, se não , ele envia para a pasta saída.

Chega a um ponto em que o programa transfere o arquivo para a pasta erros e buga, dizendo que o arquivo não existe. Por exemplo, ele acabou de transferir o arquivo `t(49).png` e ele lê novamente o mesmo arquivo! 
Engraçado é só em alguns casos que ele faz isso .

O meu código é esse :

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists(entrada + "t (" + i + ").png")) {

    string[] datas1 = Spire.Barcode.BarcodeScanner.Scan(@"C:\\QTRACK\\Entrada\\PNG\\t (" + i + ").png");

    this.textBox1.Text = datas1[0];

    foreach(string code in datas1) {
        DirectoryInfo exit = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:/QTRACK/Erro/");
        FileInfo[] teste = exit.GetFiles("*.png");
        x = teste.Length + 1;

        for (c = x; c <= 1000000000; c++) {

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(saida + code + ".png")) {
                System.IO.File.Move(entrada.ToString() + "t (" + i + ").png", erro + "e" + c + ".png");

            } else {
                System.IO.File.Move(entrada.ToString() + "t(" + i + ").png", saida + code + ".png");
            }

        }
    }
} else {

}
```

Ele dá o erro de `FileNotFoundExecption`, porém foi ele mesmo quem mudou o arquivo e tá tentando mudar de novo.

Comment: Não será por estar a fazer mil milhões de iterações no ciclo?

Comment: Mas como que eu faria isso sem essas mil milhões de interações ?

Comment: Sou inexperiênte ainda

Comment: Você está usando algum mecanismo de *thread*? Onde este código é chamado?

Answer (score 1):

O que acontece é que devido ao teu loop de 1000000000 iterações, quando o arquivo não existe na saida  `System.IO.File.Exists(saida + code + ".png") == false` ele move `entrada.ToString() + "t (" + i + ").png"` para `saida + code + ".png"`

Porém, na segunda vez, `System.IO.File.Exists(saida + code + ".png") == true` porque você já mandou o arquivo pra lá, então  ele tenta `entrada.ToString() + "t (" + i + ").png"` para algum lugar, mas esse arquivo já não existe mais nesta localização.

Eu não entendo o porque esse loop é necessário, mas acho que todos teus problemas serão resolvidos se vc simplesmente deleta-lo.

Comment: Entendii ! Obrigado @!